# strange display of images in listview

Tags: android

i have a strange problem. In my app there is a list of buddys for the actual logged in user.
The content for the list is loaded via an AsyncTask and is bound to a ListView through a BaseAdapter.

Inside the adapter within the method getView i try to load (async) an userimage for the given position (buddy) in the list. Thats working fine but the loading / showing off the images in my app looks very strange.

Have a look at the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urG6NmkY070

Here is the code of the getView methode from the BaseAdapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buddy_list_item, parent,false);
    }

    ImageView avatar        = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    TextView username       = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
    ImageView online        = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.online);
    TextView onlinestatus   = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.onlinestatus);
    TextView lastonline     = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lastonline);


    BuddyObject buddyObject = buddyListResponseObject.getResponse().getOnlineUsers().get(position);

    username.setText(buddyObject.getBuddy().getUsername());
    onlinestatus.setText(buddyObject.getBuddy().getOnline());

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date sendDate = new Date(buddyObject.getBuddy().getLastActivity()*1000);
    lastonline.setText(dateFormat.format(sendDate).toString());

    Log.d(BaseActivity.TAG, "called getView " + position);

    try {
        String url = "http://www.alfa-romeo-portal.de/arcommunity/image.php?u=" + buddyObject.getBuddy().getUserId();
        Log.d(BaseActivity.TAG, url);
        new ImageDownloadTask(avatar).execute(new URL(url));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(BaseActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

AsyncTask - ImageDownloadTask

```
public class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Bitmap> {

private ImageView imageView;

public ImageDownloadTask(ImageView imageView){
    this.imageView = imageView;
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... params) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapDownloader.loadBitmap(params[0]);
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

    if(bitmap != null && bitmap.getByteCount() > 1) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage);
    }
}
```

}

Log that shows that the method getView is called 5 times for only one buddy. How could that happen?

```
08-01 15:32:00.341  22465-22606/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app I/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ there is no buddy list...
```

08-01 15:32:00.341  22465-22606/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app I/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ there is only one buddy...
08-01 15:32:00.371  22465-22465/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ called getView 0
08-01 15:32:00.371  22465-22465/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ http://www.alfa-romeo-portal.de/arcommunity/image.php?u=4009
08-01 15:32:00.381  22465-22465/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ called getView 0
08-01 15:32:00.381  22465-22465/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ http://www.alfa-romeo-portal.de/arcommunity/image.php?u=4009
08-01 15:32:00.381  22465-22465/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ called getView 0
08-01 15:32:00.381  22465-22465/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ http://www.alfa-romeo-portal.de/arcommunity/image.php?u=4009
08-01 15:32:00.491  22465-22608/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ loaded buddy image ... http://www.alfa-romeo-portal.de/arcommunity/image.php?u=4009
08-01 15:32:00.511  22465-22465/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ called getView 0
08-01 15:32:00.511  22465-22465/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ http://www.alfa-romeo-portal.de/arcommunity/image.php?u=4009
08-01 15:32:00.511  22465-22465/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ called getView 0
08-01 15:32:00.511  22465-22465/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ http://www.alfa-romeo-portal.de/arcommunity/image.php?u=4009
08-01 15:32:00.611  22465-22609/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ loaded buddy image ... http://www.alfa-romeo-portal.de/arcommunity/image.php?u=4009
08-01 15:32:00.711  22465-22610/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ loaded buddy image ... http://www.alfa-romeo-portal.de/arcommunity/image.php?u=4009
08-01 15:32:00.811  22465-22610/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ loaded buddy image ... http://www.alfa-romeo-portal.de/arcommunity/image.php?u=4009
08-01 15:32:00.931  22465-22610/de.alfa.romeo.portal.app D/ARP-PORTAL-APP﹕ loaded buddy image ... http://www.alfa-romeo-portal.de/arcommunity/image.php?u=4009

Can anybody tell me what i did wrong?
THX

Comment: use this http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see the rest of this code, but it appears that initially all the async ImageDownloadTask are trying to add their images to the first Imageview in yout layout and then on some kind of a redraw it is finding the correct imageview to draw into.

The other thing you are going to need to fix is when the convertView is not null, you need to empty out the imageview before you load the new image because otherwise it will show the image of the last buddy you loaded into that view that got scrolled off the screen and is now being reused until your async task finishes loading the new buddy image.

Comment: I added the ImageDownloadTask code in my first post.

Comment: Added log output that shows that the method getView is called 5 times but there is only one buddy in this case. curios.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. 
It was worng to load the avatar images in the getView Method of the BaseAdapter, because
the getView Method is called more than once for a ListItem.

So i extended my Byddy object with a Bitmap object and a method to load the image for the current buddy(async).

The loadImage method is called within a for loop after the Adapter was created.

```
final BuddyListAdapter buddyListAdapter = new BuddyListAdapter(respBuddyList, this.activity);
        lvBuddies.setAdapter(buddyListAdapter);

        // load async image for every buddy
        for(BuddyObject buddy : respBuddyList.getResponse().getOnlineUsers()){
            buddy.getBuddy().setBuddyListAdapter(buddyListAdapter);
            buddy.getBuddy().loadAvatar();
        }

        Log.d(BaseActivity.TAG, "iterated over all loaded buddys...");



public class Buddy {
private String username;
private String invisible;
private String userId;
private long lastActivity;
private String buddymark;
private String invisibleMark;
private String online;
private String onlinestatusphrase;
private String statusIcon;

private Bitmap avatarImage;
private BuddyListAdapter buddyListAdapter;

public Buddy() {
}




public void loadAvatar(){
    if(buddyListAdapter != null){
        String url = "http://www.alfa-romeo-portal.de/arcommunity/image.php?u=" + userId;
        try {
            new ImageDownloadTask().execute(new URL(url));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```